# Modeling Arrivals With a Time Limit

Tags: modeling, poisson-process, interarrival-time

I have some data (sample here):

```
    TIME ARRIVALS
405    1    21
406    2    24
407    3    24
408    4    18
409    5    26
410    6    16
411    7    12
412    8    10
413    9     8
414   10    23
415   11    22
416   12    23
417   13    14
418   14    14
419   15    12
420   16     8
421   17    21
422   18    15
423   19    22
424   20    14
425   21    25
426   22    10
427   23    11
428   24    24
429   25    13
430   26    18
431   27    26
432   28    15
433   29    11
434   30    22
435   31    19
436   32     9
437   33    29
438   34    28
439   35    28
440   36     9
441   37    28
442   38    29
443   39    22
444   40    31
445   41    57
446   42    30
447   43    22
448   44    19
449   45    30
450   46    32
451   47    24
452   48    24
453   49    23
454   50    26
455   51    16
456   52    38
457   53    43
458   54    26
459   55    25
460   56    24
461   57    25
462   58    20
463   59    19
464   60    32
465   61    19
466   62    19
467   63    21
468   64    20
469   65    27
470   66    44
471   67    30
472   68    38
473   69    35
474   70    34
475   71    31
476   72    37
477   73    46
478   74    42
479   75    49
480   76    65
481   77    51
482   78    32
483   79    39
484   80    68
485   81    74
486   82    64
487   83    44
488   84    58
489   85    43
490   86    58
491   87   165
492   88   103
493   89    95
494   90   103
495   91   101
496   92    75
497   93    86
498   94   228
499   95   230
500   96   261
501   97   182
502   98   228
503   99   248
504  100   600
505  101  1438
```

that showcases the number of arrivals over discrete time intervals (days, in this case). I'm having some trouble modeling the process because of the form of the data. There is a limited time horizon for arrivals to occur, ending at day 101. As you can see, there is a small but steady increase for most of the period, but the last few days see extreme jumps that are inconsistent with the times before. Is there anything I can do to model this sort of thing?